# MediaElement possible memory leak on new media load?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, memory-leaks, mediaelement

I am developing WPF app for a media player in c# and I am using the mediaElement control to host media.

As I want the user to be able to load both video and images in the player, I ve made a simple *if-then-else* statement inside the **mediaOpened** event, to check every time that a new media is loaded, if it hasTimespan (and therefor the player sees it as a **video**) or else as a **picture**.

To check if this *if/else* statement was working, I placed a message box in each case to give me feedback that indeed the player recognizes correctly the media type.

So far so good.

I load a video, everything goes as expected and I get my message box saying "video!".

But when I load a 2nd video the message box appears 2 times.

When I load one more video, the message box appears 3 times!

Even weirder, if I load a picture next, the message box appears 4 times but instead of a sequence of message boxes like this,

"video!" "video!" "video!" "picture!", I get

"picture!" "picture!" "picture!" "picture!".

It seems that the player is storing the media (or the mediaOpened events) in some kind of a list and every time I load a new one, it checks all the media in that list and gives me a message for each one. (I haven't wrote any code to support a playlist feature yet, so I don't know where these media could be being stored...)

I ve tried stating the mediaElement's source as null when the user presses the load new media button, to make sure the mediaElement source is clean before the new media gets loaded, but it did not have any effect.

Does this sound like a memory leak? 
Am I missing a specific unloading event that I should call upon media change?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that in most online examples on how to develop a mediaplayer,

everybody suggests using this next line upon clicking the load button in the player:

*mediaElement.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement_MediaOpened);*

but no one seems to be aware that these media need to be unloaded when you load a new one, which is possible by placing the exact opposite, before we set the new source of the media element, so it would be in this order for example:

mediaElement.MediaOpened -= new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement_MediaOpened);

mediaElement.Source = new Uri(dlg.FileName);

mediaElement.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement_MediaOpened);

Hope this helps somebody out there!

Comment: Intead of doing that just put the subscription (`+=`)  in your constructor instead of the button click then all you need to do in the click is `mediaElement.Source = new Uri(dlg.FileName);`, no `+=` or `-=`